# Accessing a hardcoded response xml through Java axis webservice client code

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

Our code  calls a webservice to fetch some data. But the service provider's service is down most of the time. I have the response xml. Can some one help us with the easiest way to access the hardCoded response xml to our webservice client code. We use Java Axis Webservice. Can i host the webservice on my local machine? I have the wsdl and xsd's . Please help me how to host this service.. Or is there any simple way to access the response xml through axis webservice client..

Comment: Hi found a simple way.. I placed the response xml in tomcat.. and gave it as the end point url for my service. ex: http://localhost:8080/webService/response.xml. When my client app accessed it, i got ADB exception. So i removed the <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> and <soapenv:Body> tags. After that it worked fine. I'm able to access the response objects in my client code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways available to create web service from wsdl. If you want to create it manually then you follow [these steps](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish4.html)

The most easiest way is to use some tools that can generate the webservice for you as Netbeans has a wizard which can create the webservice from wsdl. All methods and neccessary files generates automatically. see [Developing Webservices from wsdl using Netbeans](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2008/03/developing_webs.html)

After creating webservice you can host it from your local machine. Netbeans also has the option to run and deploy the webservice.

Comment: Hi I have a response xml ..  All i need is to send this response xml when i access my end point url.. CAn u say me an easiest way

Comment: Hi found a simple way.. I placed the response xml in tomcat.. and gave it as the end point url for my service. ex: http://localhost:8080/webService/response.xml. When my client app accessed it, i got ADB exception. So i removed the <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> and <soapenv:Body> tags. After that it worked fine. I'm able to access the response objects in my client code.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp %AXISCLASSPATH% org.apache.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://wsdl_url
```

This will help you to generate the WebService from the WSDL.

Comment: Hi found a simple way.. I placed the response xml in tomcat.. and gave it as the end point url for my service. ex: http://localhost:8080/webService/response.xml. When my client app accessed it, i got ADB exception. So i removed the <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> and <soapenv:Body> tags. After that it worked fine. I'm able to access the response objects in my client code.